# Why do I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I make a new Instance of a my class?

Tags: java

I need to make a Instance of this class but when I try I get a NullPointerException.
Can you tell me why and how to fix, I'm still pretty new at this.

```
public class NewTryPoints {

private int[] pointX;
private int[] pointY;
private static final int topix = 5;

public NewTryPoints(){
    setX();
    setY();
    }

public void setX(){

    pointX[0] = 1;
    pointX[1] = (int)Math.random() * ( 50 - 1 ) * topix;
    pointX[2] = 2 + (int)(Math.random() * ((50 - 2) + 1)) * topix;
};

public void setY(){

    pointY[0] = 1 * topix;
    pointY[1] = 2 + (int)(Math.random() * ((50 - 2) + 1)) * topix;
    pointY[2] = 1 * topix;

};

public int[] getpointX() { return pointX; };
public int[] getpointY() { return pointY; };

}
```

**other class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
NewTryPoints points = new NewTryPoints();   

  }

}
```

Comment: On which line do you get the NPE? Provice a stacktrace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using references **pointX** and **pointY** without assigning them memory, hence they are null and a NullPointerException is raised. You should first do ..

```
public NewTryPoints(){
    pointX = new int[3];
    pointY = new int[3];
    setX();
    setY();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the array.

add this in the constructor before the calls to setx and sety.

```
pointX = new int[3];
pointY = new int[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize the arrays at all:

```
private int[] pointX;
private int[] pointY;
```

Trying to access either in the set-method results in null, as they do not contain a reference to an array object yet!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the array before you use it in Java. Please initialize the arrays before you set the values in `setX` and `setY` methods in the constructor

```
public NewTryPoints(){
    //initializing the arrays
    pointX = new int[3]; 
    pointY = new int[3];
    setX();
    setY();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you are calling `setX()` and `setY()` which in turn fill your arrays with values. Problem is you did not initialize these arrays:

```
pointX = new int[5]; // 5 is just for the example
pointY = new int[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your references to arrays.  This means that

```
private int[] pointX;
```

is the same as

```
private int[] pointX = null;
```

so when you do

```
pointX[0] = ...
```

it throws an NullPointerException.

One way you could have seen this is by looking at this in your debugger.

Most likely you intended to write

```
private int[] pointX = new int[3];
```